# 2 column responsive masonry-like layout without javascript?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a number of divs of dynamic height I would like to place into two columns that display immediately after the other, ideally without javascript (and libraries such as packery, masonry etc).

I've begun with `display: inline-block` [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/holove)

I've also tried following [Easy Masonry Layout With Flexbox](http://thenewcode.com/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox) to no avail [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/digumu)

I could structure the DOM into separate columns but this isn't ideal as they need to collapse into a single column on mobile.

[image: diagram]

Of course, simply using inline-block results in an unwanted gap along the lines of this:

[image: unwanted gap]

**EDIT:** Updated diagrams to be more clear about desired result - left to right columns with no unwanted gaps

Comment: Assuming you want these element going from left to right and then down and across the answer is no!

Answer (score 3):

You should set float:left css to all your divs.

```
<div style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
   these divs will be displayed next to each other.
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: floating left does not work once the items are not of equal height

Comment: For me it is working even with different heights. Can you create add you code too. or plunker ?

Comment: Here is an example on jsbin, the taller item breaks the layout: http://jsbin.com/jugimuyone

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS columns](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) now without worrying too much about browser support. Older IE versions are the only potential blocker, depending on your audience. There are also still quite a few browser quirks to work around, but I've been using them in production for a while now. It's your only real option for a masonry-like layout today, without using JS.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the items need to go from left to right, not in typical top to bottom columns

Comment: @waffl you should be able to get what you need from flexbox then. Just play around with these parameters on the parent (align-content and/or justify-content, flex-direction) and on the children(flex-grow/flex-shrink)
 
[See here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution you can use flex for this
CSS

```
.flex-container {padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: space-around; }
.flex-item {background: tomato; padding: 5px; width: 200px; height: 150px; margin-top: 10px; line-height: 150px; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 3em; text-align: center; } 
#fl-item{height:200px;}
```

And HTML

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item" id="fl-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

And you can see working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hc0J9TucxWxnh0hVbVkR?p=preview)

Comment: This does not appear to work a there is still an unwanted gap in the top row